# Best way to store mapping from strings to ints, and the other way around at the same time?

Tags: c++, c++11

Best way to store mapping from strings to ints, and the other way around at the same time?

For example, I have a vector called columnNames, and I would like to
be able to get a column name given its index, that is its position, but then
also given its position I would like to get its name. One way to do this
is to use a map and store column names in order, and this way
I will be able to do what I want, but I wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: Can one integer value map to multiple strings, or the other way around?

Answer (score 6):

Depends what you mean by "better". Boost.MultiIndex is a very flexible way do this and other things like it, while Boost.Bimap is more specialized.

For this specific case, you could use a `map<string,int>` together with a `vector<const string*>` for the lookup from index to string (because indexes by nature form a contiguous sequence). The pointers in the vector point to keys in the map. This is easiest if you don't modify the columns once they're set up, but even if you do it's possible to update the `vector` to match.

Comment: Why not just use a map? If I want to go from string to int I can use the map as m[someString], and if I want to go from int to string, I can just get the i-th element in the map?

Comment: For manual simulation of Boost.MultiIndex, the secondary container should have iterators rather than pointers into the primary container, i.e. `vector<map<string,int>::iterator>` for reasons explained by the [Boost.MultiIndex docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/performance.html#simulation).

Comment: @user3111311: if you don't mind the reverse lookup being slow then a `map` alone is fine (although I'm not sure what you mean by "ith element" because element `i` in the iteration order of the map is not the element with value `i`). Perhaps wrongly, I assumed that you wouldn't ask the question if slow lookup was OK :-)

Comment: @TemplateRex: if you want to (for example) delete by index, yes you'd probably want map iterators in the vector to save a map lookup. `mymap.erase(myvec[i])` rather than `mymap.erase(mymap.find(myvec[i]))`. Just for looking up the column name it's not necessary.

Comment: Sure, for lookup it doesn't matter, but in general it's best to provide `O(log N)` behavior for all map like operations (lookup, insert, erase) so as not to surprise future users of such code. A loop over a map that has `O(N)` members can quickly degenerate into a quadratic algorithm e.g. :-)

Comment: You can't provide `O(log N)` erase from an arbitrary position in a vector regardless of whether the vector contains string pointers or iterators. So given that there is a vector, the complexity of the operations would seem to be a separate issue from what's in it. If `O(log N)` erase is required then use Bimap or two maps (or unordered_map in place of map wherever you aren't concerned about the risk of pathological levels of hash collisions). But since the number in the map is an *index*, it may be that "erase" requires the whole thing to be updated anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Not aware of something in C++11 but this might work:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

> Boost.Bimap is a bidirectional maps library for C++. With Boost.Bimap
>   you can create associative containers in which both types can be used
>   as key. A bimap can be thought of as a combination of a
>   std::map and a std::map. The learning curve of bimap is
>   almost flat if you know how to use standard containers. A great deal
>   of effort has been put into mapping the naming scheme of the STL in
>   Boost.Bimap. The library is designed to match the common STL
>   containers.

A (probably worse, O(n) ) solution with lambdas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

map<string, int> m = {{"hello", 1}, {"world", 2}};



int main() {


    int findVal = 2;
    auto it = find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [findVal](const pair<string,int> & p) {
        return p.second == findVal;
    });

    if(it != m.end())
        cout << it->second << "->" << it->first << "\n";

    string findStr = "hello";
    auto itStr = find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [findStr](const pair<string,int> & p) {
        return p.first.compare(findStr) == 0;
    });

    if(itStr != m.end())
        cout << itStr->second << "->" << itStr->first << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

---

If you're searching for something horribly simple (and probably terribly inefficient too), use this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

map<string, int> m = {{"hello", 1}, {"world", 2}};

class notFound
{ };

string findFromInt(const int& val)
{
    map<string,int>::iterator it = m.begin();
    while(it != m.end())
    {
        if(it->second == val)
            return it->first;

        it++;
    }
    throw new notFound();
}

int findFromString(const string& str)
{
    map<string,int>::iterator it = m.begin();
    while(it != m.end())
    {
        if(it->first.compare(str) == 0)
            return it->second;

        it++;
    }
    throw new notFound();
}


int main() {


    int findVal = 2;
    try {
        string str = findFromInt(findVal);

        cout << "found: " << str;
    } catch(notFound *obj) {
        cout << "Value not found";
    }


    string findStr = "hgggllo";
    try {
        int val = findFromString(findStr);

        cout << "found: " << val;
    } catch(notFound *obj) {
        cout << "Value not found";
    }




    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/2FP64h

Comment: a bit more complicated that I really need :(

Comment: Then go for boost bitmap, you don't need to know the internals of that one

Comment: I wrote the above example since you were asking for C++11 solutions

Comment: Too complicated also, I would rather not use stuff outside the standard.

Comment: The C++11 above example is completely standard-conformant. What are you searching for if you put the C++11 tag into the question?

Comment: Yeah but it is ugly as a turtle!

Comment: oooooh, please don't I will cry too :(

Answer (score 1):

In your usecase, I would prefer the method you mention (map + vector) over bi-maps.
Your usecase is special in a way that your ints start at zero and are consecutive.

Your proposed solution is simple, highly efficient (especially hashmap, aka. unordered_map + vector) and does not require any outside library.

Comment: you mean Steve Jessop's solution?

Comment: I was refering to your own. "One way to do this is to use a map and store column names in order"

Comment: I thought that was what you meant with "store column names in order". Array/vector/(lists, please no) all do that. A vector is easy to use, has O(1) access to an element given its index so I thought it was the logical choice for storing a bag of someting in order

Comment: But can't I also get the i-th element in a map? Why use vector?

Comment: @user311311 getting the ith element in a map involves starting at begin() and iterating through the binary tree nodes - it's relatively slow, but if you've a sane number of columns (e.g. hundreds or fewer) and only do this infrequently (a few times a second or less) on good hardware, you may not care....

Answer (score 0):

You may use a biderectional map, like this one:

[boost bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)